# Generatinig laguerre polynomial

Tags: calculus

I try to find the sum
$$F(x,t)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } t^{k^2} L_k(x)$$
But we know that 
$$\int_0^1 F(x,t) \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \Gamma (1-i) U(-i,1,x)+\frac{1}{2} \Gamma (1+i) U(i,1,x)$$
Coulf you find the function F ?

Comment: What is the function $U$?

Comment: Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the Second Kind